# Pandas: List of dictionaries behaves like list of strings when selected from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I read from a csv file and as a result, a Pandas DataFrame is created and first row, for example, looks like this:

```
id      keywords
0       [{'key1': 'string'}, {'key2': 'string2'}, {'key3': 'string3'}]
```

So, when I first saw the data, I thought that it was a list of dictionaries. When I checked the types, it's in fact a list of strings. Because of that, I cannot do something like `list['key1']` to select the value of `key1`, for example.

I also should mention that I'm using the code below to read the file and get the first row of DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='|')
keywords = df["keywords"].tolist()
```

And the output of `keywords` is like this:

`[{'key1': 'string'}, {'key2': 'string2'}, {'key3': 'string3'}]`

which is exactly the same thing in the first row.

My question is, how do I extract the value of `key1`? I cannot use `keywords['key1']` because it gives me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. I tried `keywords[0]` for example but it didn't work out as well. So, what's the problem here?

Edit: I came up with a solution, but as a huge idiot, I deleted my own code accidentally... What I did was remove brackets first, then use `split(',')` and take the first element, if I'm trying to pick `string1`, for example. After that, I had `{'key1': 'string'}` as the first element, then removed curly brackets and used `split(':')`. This time, I picked last element which is `'string'` and I removed `'` character too.

Once I got some free time, I'll post the code here. It might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and not generic way is typing `keywords[0]["key1"]`

I would go with a simple function that takes the requested key as an argument and return the relevant value.

Iterate each element at the list, for each element which is a dict, iterate over the items (you have only one, but this solution supports more) and return the value of the key when approaching it.

A simple implementation for that:

```
keywords = [{'key1': 'string'}, {'key2': 'string2'}, {'key3': 'string3'}]

def find_by_key(key):
  for elem in keywords:
    for k,v in elem.items():
      if k == key:
        return elem[k]

print (find_by_key("key1"))

>>> 'string'
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer! Sadly, this doesn't work. 

As I said in the question, `keywords` seems like a list of dictionaries, but it's basically list of strings. Because of that, I cannot use `key` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you expect but you can do something like:

```
eval(df['keywords'][0])[0]['key1']
```

That way you extract it from first row, if you want to apply it to all rows just do:

```
df.apply(lambda x: eval(x['keywords'])[0]['key1'], axis=1)
```

you can also assign it to new column

```
df['key1'] = df.apply(lambda x: eval(x['keywords'])[0]['key1'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer! This didn't work, because it's not a list of dictionaries. It's basically a list of strings and I cannot use a key value.

Also, a quick question: why did you use `eval`? I've seen many people warning others using `eval` because it's kind of dangerous, though I don't know the reason.

Comment: Eval to convert string into dictionary, it works for me on your example, can you show me what error do you get or what is not working?